# How to make a 2D or 3D fire appear at an exit by probability

Tags: anylogic

I am currently working on a fire evacuation project and would like to have a fire appear at an exit in 2D and 3D when I run the simulation, using probability.

I've noticed that there is a 3D fire object in the anylogic 3D objects, but I'm not sure of the code or method in using it for my simulation model. My current model has a random probability to obstruct an exit (3 different exits) when I run the simulation, which means the pedestrians will know that this exit isn't available and will find an alternative route closest to them unobstructed.

This is the code on the probability of exit obstruction at the main agent actions on

```
if(uniform(0,1)<0.8){ // 20% probability of obstruction
    availableExits.add(targetLine1);
}
if(uniform(0,1)<0.8){ // 20% probability of obstruction
    availableExits.add(targetLine2);
}
if(uniform(0,1)<0.8){ // 20% probability of obstruction
    availableExits.add(targetLine3);
}
```

This is the layout of my project, where the targetLine are the exits:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 3 instances of the 3D fire object, move them the locations of your targetLines.
Call them fire1, fire2 and fire3, corresponding to the naming of the targetLines.

In the OnStartup code in your Main, use the following code to make them invisible at model start:

```
fire1.setVisible(false);
fire2.setVisible(false);
fire3.setVisible(false);
```

> Note: You cannot just uncheck the option "Visible" of the fire properties. Although this will make it invisible, it does not allow you to later make it visible by code again. Therefore use code to make it invisible at model startup.

To "couple" the visibility of the fires and the obstruction of exits, just extend the exisiting code:

```
if(uniform(0,1)<0.8){ // 20% probability of obstruction
    availableExits.add(targetLine1);
}
else{
    fire1.setVisible(true);
}

if(uniform(0,1)<0.8){ // 20% probability of obstruction
    availableExits.add(targetLine2);
}
else{
    fire2.setVisible(true);
}

if(uniform(0,1)<0.8){ // 20% probability of obstruction
    availableExits.add(targetLine3);
}
else{
    fire3.setVisible(true);
}
```

> Note: The 3D object *fire* of AnyLogic is not "really" 3D. It actually only expands in 2 dimensions, which means that in 2D view you can not see it, and in 3D only as a "flat" surface.

To avoid that, maybe just use a normal rectangle shape, add z-size to it (so now it is a 3D volume) and give it a red semi-tranparent color. That probably doesn't look very realistic, but at least it is visible from all sides.

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly but when I add in the fire object, they don't appear in the floor layout. In other words I can only see the fire in the 3D window. Other 3D objects seem to appear, is it because I am using the student version?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with your version. The fire object is just modeled "flat", like a paper carton, so from above you only see a "line" ( or nothing, because line thickness = 0). Thats why I wrote the fire object is not so good. You could however use the orientation of the fire properties to rotate it, then you can see it from 2D, but it will look weird in 3D. Maybe you import your own 3D model of a fire? Or you just visualise it by primitives ( coloured cubes) ?

Comment: Ok. I managed to show some type of indication that there is a fire now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can do this. I can think of 3 for now but I'm sure people can suggest more:

You can put the fire 3D object at you exit and use a condition on object's visible property ([check this tutorial from AnyLogic](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fagentbased%2FAir%20Defense%20system%2FADS_Phase_4.html))

You can put the fire object at your exit, make it invisible and use `fire.setVisible(true);` to make the fire object visible randomly.

You can have a population of fire agents and move them to your exit points when necessary.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, I just need a code for making the fire appear at the required obstructed exit.